# Is bitwise comparison on boolean considered wrong?

Tags: c#, bitwise-operators

Today I received a review comment and I'm mostly curious what 'the world' thinks of this

```
var result = true;
foreach (var item in _items)
{
    // left some code out since it's not relevant for this question

    // Is this considered a bad practice?
    result &= item.Result;
}
```

The reviewer stated that he would not use the bit-wise comparison because it would fail if the type would ever changed to something else then a bool.

In the context, it doesn't make sense to ever change the type to something else then a bool. Since I use this bitwise-check really often (e.g. in overloading equals methods) I was wondering if the reviewer was right, and this is indeed considered wrong/bad.

Comment: How would you do that differently? How could you support types other than `bool` in this case? I don't think that using a built in operator can be considered "bad practice" on it's own - it's very circumstances dependent. Having said that, I think this question is off-topic as "primarily opinion based".

Comment: It is an assignment, not a comparison.  When it gets a reviewer so confused then it is indeed a bad practice, the C# language otherwise has no problem with it.  It is a very bad practice in the C language, might have something to do with it.

Comment: There is any reason to continue to loop once _result_ turns false?

Comment: If the type ever changed to something else than a `bool` the whole loop's logic would no longer apply, so that's a silly argument. What is true is that this is not considered very intuitive to *most* people, but that's just because they're not necessarily comfortable with boolean algebra (as opposed to boolean expressions). In no case is this a *bitwise* operator, though.

Comment: In the code you posted it would still continue with the foreach loop even after the result became false, which I haven't seen done a lot. Usually you want to abort once the result turns false and not proceed after the first failure, or if you want to continue you should keep a list of items that caused the failure. Here you say "at least one failure occured" but it's impossible to tell how many or because of which object.

Comment: This is debatable. IMO - Itis not obvious to a me on what it is doing and had to lookup

Comment: at list it's a [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators) feature, so why not? As long as you remember that bitwise operator always executes both sides of expression regardless to their results, I think that's OK.

Comment: So shorter and clearer: `var result = _items.All(x => x.Result); `

It's not that bitwise operations are bad, but because your code is not obvious.

If possible, code should be written shorter and more obvious.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments and answer. I understand the example presented in the example is not clear enough. In retrospect maybe I should've posted the actual case. But the provided insights already give me an answer I can work with. Thanks and I guess @ZoharPeled is right, I guess it's also a large part 'taste' in that sense.

Comment: PS: In the actual case, I do want to iterate over all elements, and do not break out the loop when the first item returns false. So I realize now I have some portion of 'side effect programming' which I better have another look at :)

Answer (score -2):

if you use

```
if (item.Result) 
     continue; 
else 
    result = false;
```

you get the best performance, and it's independent of the type of result, if this is a concern. Not nicest notation, but least CPU use.

The `result&=` causes a read and write operation to 'result', and this is omitted with this solution. The inversed  `if` is necessary to avoid the need to test for `if (!item.Result)`, which would be slower.

As others already said, if the only meaning of your loop is testing all items without doing anything else, you can add a break; after result = false.

Comment: Could any of the downvoters explain, what's wrong with that ? It's not about bit operation, it's an alternative solution to the problem.

Comment: He didn't ask for another solution. He asked if what he did is wrong.

Comment: So an expected answer is just "Yes, it's bad". Without how to do better ? Weird. However...